# Freeform 4 and ExpressionEngine Core

Tags: ee2, solspace-freeform

Does Freeform 4x (the free version) work with ExpressionEngine Core 2.8.1 ?
I uploaded the Freeform folder into the third_party folder on my server and refreshed the modules page. I wasnt able to see Freeform under it.
Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

Minutes after posting this I remembered blindly copied the files. 
My bad. I remember seeing a video that says the developers of add-ons specify the folder structure where the files need to be copied.

Comment: All third party add-ons should be placed, still within their respective folder, into /system/expressionengine/third-party